# Wordpress фильтр ACF + jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Всем привет
Вопрос по фильтрации в wordpress по полям ACF.

Мне нужно создать виджет фильтра по площади от и до

Я сделал фронтенд часть, а вот бэкэнд не могу никак.

наткнулся на статью [Creating a WP archive with custom field filter](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-wp-archive-custom-field-filter/)

Мне примерно понятно как там работает код, но в том примере код генерирует url и прописывает в него точное значение переменной, которую вибираешь

Для меня же нужно чтобы массив выбирался между двумя переменными

```
'key' => 'full_are', // название произвольного поля
  'value' => array($min_val, $max_val), // переданное значение произвольного поля
  'type' => 'numeric', // тип поля
  'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
```

Как можно получить $min_val, $max_val мне примерно понятно, но как мне сгенерировать ссылку вида **/?min_area=0?max_area=350** ?
По аналогии с встроенным в woocommerce min_price и max_price

Может есть какие примеры с полным кодом, чтобы разобрать ?

Спасибо!